# Detectar valor document.getElementById() dentro de un array

Tags: javascript, array, id

Tengo una galería de imágenes donde intento que cuando el usuario haga click en cada una de ellas se muestre esa misma imagen en grande. Lo logro hacer con su correspondiente "id" y con javascript.

Ejemplo:

```
<li><img id="azul" src="img/azul.png" ></li>
<li><img id="amarillo" src="img/amarillo.png" ></li>
<li><img id="verde" src="img/verde.png" ></li>
<li><img id="rojo" src="img/verde.png" ></li>

<script>
// Get the modal //
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");


var img1 = document.getElementById("azul");
var img2 = document.getElementById("amarillo");
var img3 = document.getElementById("verde");
var img3 = document.getElementById("rojo");

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img-modal-grande");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

//Click en imágenes a mostrar
img1.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "flex";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

img2.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "flex";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
img3.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "flex";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}
img4.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "flex";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

Hasta aquí bien, pero claro si son 20 imágenes e intento hacerlo en un array al intentar coger el valor dentro de [b]document.getElementById()[/b] no lo reconoce

```
<script>

var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

//Coge el valor para luego devolverlo al hacer onclick


var myArray = ['azul', 'amarillo', 'verde', 'rojo' ];

for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){

    var img = document.getElementById(myArray[i]);

    //Prueba añadiendo de nuevo el valor a id, donde aquí si lo reconoce pero al hacer clien en la imagen luego no hace la fución.
    //var img = document.getElementById(myArray[i]).id = myArray[i];

}

var modalImg = document.getElementById("img-modal-grande");
var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");

//Click en imágenes a mostrar
img.onclick = function(){
  modal.style.display = "flex";
  modalImg.src = this.src;
  captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
}


// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>
```

**texto en negrita**
¿Cómo podría hacer que reconozca el valor del id dentro del array para luego devolverlo o llamarlo al hacer click en cada imagen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo agregándoles una clase a dichas imágenes, como por ejemplo la clase **`imagen`**.

```html
<li><img class="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/JTxrumw.png" width="10%"></li>
<li><img class="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/3errohJ.png" width="10%"></li>
<li><img class="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/Iqx3tiy.png" width="10%"></li>
<li><img class="imagen" src="https://i.imgur.com/L7hyDOT.png" width="10%"></li>

<h2>Aqui se mostrara la imagen cuando hagas clic</h2>
<img src="" id="resultado" width="50%">

<script>
    document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        // Si el elemento seleccionado no tiene el selector correcto, abandona...
        if (!event.target.matches('.imagen')) return;
        event.preventDefault();
        // Muestras en consola el evento capturado (la imagen)
        // console.log(event.target)
        // Asignas al IMG vacio el SRC de la imagen clickeada
        document.getElementById('resultado').src = event.target.src;
    }, false);
</script>
```

Básicamente tienes tu listado de imágenes y un lugar en donde mostrar la imagen como resultado, creamos un evento que escucha todo el documento y detecta el **evento click** en un objeto, pero si ese evento no coincide con la clase **imagen** entonces automáticamente abandona el evento, de lo contrario le asigna su atributo **`src`** que contiene la **`url`** de la imagen a la imagen más grande (**`resultado`**).

Answer (score 1):

No te lo reconoce por que el id debe de estar entre comillas ....getElementById('elementID'). Intenta utilizando el caracter backtick (`) que significaría que estas utilizando template strings. Así :

```js
const img = `document.getElementById('${myArray[i]}')`
```

Comment: Así es, en principio lo reconoce utilizando esas comitllas que cita julitree, pero es cierto que luego no me reconoce el valor fuera del array.